# How to Rotate an SQL Server SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a 3 columns I'm interested with, each column have a 26 rows in it.
This is the normal select statement.

```
SELECT <Column01>, <Column02>, <Column03> FROM <Table01>
WHERE <conditions>
```

This is what it returns

```
Column01  | Column02  | Column03
----------+-----------+----------
Item01    | 0         | None
Item02    | 1         | Med
Item03    | 2         | None
Item04    | 0         | Med
Item05    | 7         | Bad
Item06    | 1         | Good
...
```

I want to rotate it to be like this.

```
Item01  | Item02| Item03 | Item04  | Item05 | Item06 | ...
--------+-------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
0       | 1     | 2      | 0       | 7      | 1      |
None    | Med   | None   | Med     | Bad    | Good   |
```

How can I achieve this?
Where `Column01` is `VARCHAR(MAX)`,  `Column02` is `INT`, `Column03` is `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

Comment: `each column have a 26 rows in it.` i'd be very worried if each column had different number of rows! This looks like a pivot / unpivot combination, perhaps a dynamic one, did you search for those terms?

Comment: @siggemannen yes I did try that but it didn't work. if there is an xml solution it would be welcomed too. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

> **PIVOT** rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output. **UNPIVOT** carries out the opposite operation to PIVOT by rotating columns of a table-valued expression into column values.

```sql
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

-- Sample table
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    Column01 VARCHAR(50),
    Column02 INT,
    Column03 VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Inserting sample data
INSERT INTO YourTable (Column01, Column02, Column03)
VALUES
    ('Item01', 0, 'None'),
    ('Item02', 1, 'Med'),
    ('Item03', 2, 'None'),
    ('Item04', 0, 'Med'),
    ('Item05', 7, 'Bad'),
    ('Item06', 1, 'Good');

-- Query to pivot the data
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Column01)
        FROM YourTable
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = '
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
    SELECT ' + @columns + '
    FROM (
        SELECT Column01, Value, RowNum
        FROM (
            SELECT Column01, CAST(Column02 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Column02, CAST(Column03 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Column03
            FROM YourTable
        ) AS Source
        UNPIVOT (
            Value FOR RowNum IN (Column02, Column03)
        ) AS unpivoted
    ) AS Source
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Value) FOR Column01 IN (' + @columns + ')
    ) AS PivotTable';

-- Execute dynamic SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

SQLFiddle [here](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=58db18a5-2c89-40d4-bca4-5fe58d54d188).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
with data as (
    select *
    from (
        VALUES  (N'Item01', 0, N'None')
        ,   (N'Item02', 1, N'Med')
        ,   (N'Item03', 2, N'None')
        ,   (N'Item04', 0, N'Med')
        ,   (N'Item05', 7, N'Bad')
        ,   (N'Item06', 1, N'Good')
    ) t (Column01,Column02,Column03)
)
select  max(case when column01 = 'Item01' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item02' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item03' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item04' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item05' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item06' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item07' THEN d2.col END)
,   max(case when column01 = 'Item08' THEN d2.col END)
-- You get the picture
from data d
cross apply (
    select cast(column02 as nvarchar(max)) AS col
    ,   0 as sort
    union all
    select column03
    ,   1 as sort
    ) d2
group by d2.sort
```

This is called conditional aggregation, since you do a condition `case when column01 = 'Item01' THEN d2.col END` inside a MAX aggregation function.

This part

```sql
cross apply (
    select cast(column02 as nvarchar(max)) AS col
    ,   0 as sort
    union all
    select column03
    ,   1 as sort
    ) d2
```

creates rows from the two columns, which can be used to group on later.

This version is non-dynamic, so you have to copypaste all your columns. There are examples on how to do it dynamically as well.